# Prevent laravel testing $this->get() from throwing HTTP exception when status code is not 200

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I use laravel 5.4. When in my tests I do something like:

```
$this->get("/api/test")->assertStatus(422)->assertJson([
        "status" => "ok"
]);
```

I get an HttpException when status code is 422, even though I'm totally ready for this -- and I'm even expecting it. My problem is that exception prevents my asserts, so that `assertJson` just doesn't work.

`$this->expectException(HttpException::class)` doesn't help since it catches this exception and stops, so this begins to pass:

```
$this->expectException(HttpException::class)
$this->get("/api/test")->assertStatus(422)->assertJson([
        "status" => "ok"
]);
$this->assertTrue(false);
```

I see I can catch this exception myself, but then I won't be able to apply my asserts to the response in an easy way. How can I work around that trouble?

Comment: Maybe this approach would be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835671/laravel-5-unit-testing-status-code-500-expected-200

Comment: @AlexSlipknot uh, no `action` method found =c

Comment: I think you can try method `->assertResponseStatus(422);` See https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/testing-a-403-response-status-after-submiting-a-form-in-laravel-51

Answer (score 0):

The validation errors only get converted to json response on a json or ajax request. Try this.

```
$this->getJson("/api/test")->assertStatus(422)->assertJson([
        "status" => "ok"
]);
```